# wagtail django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s); Fields doesn't exist anywhere

Tags: python, django, wagtail

my python manage.py makemigrations return error with message

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 268, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (seo_title_fr, title_fr, search_description_en, slug_en, seo_title_en, slug_fr, search_description_fr, title_en) specified for PostPage
```

I did serch everywhere in the code where are this fields I didn't find theme at all I did search in database wagtailcore_page I didn't find that fields

```
id |     path     | depth | numchild |                         title                         |                     slug                      | live | has_unpublished_changes |                        url_path                         |                          seo_title                          | show_in_menus |                                                               search_description                                                                | go_live_at | expire_at | expired | content_type_id | owner_id | locked |  latest_revision_created_at   |      first_published_at       | live_revision_id |       last_published_at       |                      draft_title                      | locked_at | locked_by_id |           translation_key            | locale_id | alias_of_id |                       url_path_en                       | url_path_fr
```

I did search in all the code including migrations but not found anything

I did try : `python manage.py update_translation_fields` but no luck

my model is :

```
import json
from django.db import models

from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse,HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.forms import FileField
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField, StreamField
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, InlinePanel, MultiFieldPanel, StreamFieldPanel, FieldRowPanel, PageChooserPanel
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from apps.start_project.google_captcha import google_captcha_validate
from colorfield.fields import ColorField
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import (
    FieldPanel, FieldRowPanel,
    InlinePanel, MultiFieldPanel
)
from wagtail.contrib.forms.models import AbstractEmailForm, AbstractFormField, AbstractFormSubmission, FORM_FIELD_CHOICES
from wagtail.contrib.forms.forms import FormBuilder
from wagtail.images.fields import WagtailImageField
from wagtail.contrib.forms.views import SubmissionsListView
from wagtail.documents import get_document_model
from .blocks import blocks

class PostPage(Page):
    
    template_path = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)

    title_html = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    description = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)
    keywords = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)

    body = StreamField(
        [
            ("widget_body", blocks.widgetBodyBlock()),
        ],
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name =_('body'),
    )

    panels = [
        FieldRowPanel([
            FieldPanel("title_html"),
            FieldPanel("description"),
            FieldPanel("keywords"),
            FieldPanel("template_path"),
        ]),
        StreamFieldPanel("body"),
    ]
```

I don't understand
[image]

Comment: This looks like the sort of change the [wagtail-modeltranslation](https://wagtail-modeltranslation-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package might apply - do you have that installed?

Comment: @gasman Yes I did install  wagtail-modeltranslatio